# Is it possible to specify a parameter as required for one endpoint and optional as another in Openapi 3.0?

Tags: swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

I’m using Openapi 3.0 and I am trying to create a query parameter that is required for one endpoint and optional for another. Since parameters are now defined using schemas, I don’t know if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible - both in OpenAPI 3.0 and 2.0. In the context of parameters, the `required` attribute is a parameter-level attribute, not a schema attribute.

```yaml
paths:
  /something:
    get:
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: foo
          required: true  # <-----
          schema:
            type: string
      ...
  /something-else:
    get:
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: foo
          required: false  # <----- Can be omitted because parameters are optional by default
          schema:
            type: string
      ...
```